# How to set breakpoints for different screen widths and heights

Tags: css

> PS: I'm very new to CSS and I'm trying my head around to work on a
>   mobile responsive UI, so please spare me if anything silly!

I have two devices with their widths and widths set as `360X640` and `375X667`. I'm trying to write the css for these using `@media` but unable to make it work. The **breakpoints** which I set seems to be not working properly. Below is my code

```
@media(max-width: 360px){
  .un-progress{
    height: 10px !important; 
    margin-top: -0.325em;
    margin-left: -2.75em;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
  }
  .finished_time{
    margin-left: 6.25em;
    margin-top: -0.8em
  }
  .left_time{
    margin-left: 22.0em;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
  }
}


@media (min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 375px){
  .un-progress{
    height: 10px !important; 
    margin-top: -0.325em;
    margin-left: -2.75em;
    margin-right: 1.5em;
  }
  .finished_time{
    margin-left: 6.25em;
    margin-top: -0.8em
  }
  .left_time{
    margin-left: 22.0em;
    margin-top: -2.5em;
  }
}
}
```

Comment: just reverse your css... write first `(min-width: 361px) and (max-width: 375px) ` and after `(max-width: 360px)`

Comment: Of course they don't work - the CSS is identical. Plus, you have an extra closing curly brace

Comment: Below 360px and between 360px to 375px  your css is same. Check it once again.

Comment: your both role are exact same css so it might working because there is not different styles for different width

Comment: @ManishPatel Your suggestion worked! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using below css.

```
media only screen
  and (max-device-width: 360px){
      .un-progress{
           height: 10px !important; 
           margin-top: -0.325em;
           margin-left: -2.75em;
           margin-right: 1.5em;
      }
     .finished_time{
        margin-left: 6.25em;
        margin-top: -0.8em
      }
      .left_time{
        margin-left: 22.0em;
        margin-top: -2.5em;
      }
}


@media only screen
   and (min-device-width: 361px) 
   and (max-device-width: 375px){
     .un-progress{
        height: 10px !important; 
        margin-top: -0.325em;
        margin-left: -2.75em;
        margin-right: 1.5em;
     }
     .finished_time{
        margin-left: 6.25em;
        margin-top: -0.8em
     }
     .left_time{
        margin-left: 22.0em;
        margin-top: -2.5em;
     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you ca use "all" for this subject.

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
     .un-progress{
        height: 10px !important; 
        margin-top: -0.325em;
        margin-left: -2.75em;
        margin-right: 1.5em;
      }
      .finished_time{
        margin-left: 6.25em;
        margin-top: -0.8em
      }
      .left_time{
        margin-left: 22.0em;
        margin-top: -2.5em;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you should know beforehand when developing responsive. **DON'T** have a media query for every device. You'll end up

1. Having a media query for each device.
2. The maintainability of your code will be so difficult, especially when scaling
3. End up with large CSS files which will be bad for page performance.

The best way for a responsive CSS would be to follow the pattern of designing for mobile first and gradually making changes as the media queries get larger. eg

```
      .un-progress {
        height: 10px !important; 
        margin-top: -0.325em;
        margin-left: -2.75em;
        margin-right: 1.5em;
      }
      .finished_time {
        margin-left: 6.25em;
        margin-top: -0.8em
      }
      .left_time {
        margin-left: 22.0em;
        margin-top: -2.5em;
      }

    @media (min-width: 480px) {
        .un-progress{
          // changes here
        }
        .finished_time{
          // changes here
        }
        .left_time{
          // changes here
        }
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .un-progress{
          // changes here
        }
        .finished_time{
          // changes here
        }
        .left_time{
          // changes here
        }
      }
    }

    @media (min-width: 1024px) {
        .un-progress{
          // changes here
        }
        .finished_time{
          // changes here
        }
        .left_time{
          // changes here
        }
       }
     }
```

(change the media query min-widths as approriate) This would give you a much cleaner and lightweight CSS